# How to access data in Microstrategy using a JAVA API

Tags: java, sdk, microstrategy

I have Microstrategy Analytics Desktop installed on my system, and added a connection to the local Oracle connection and am able to view a oracle db on Microstrategy webapp. My goal is to access this data using Java code. I have downloaded Microstrategy SDK and can see a jar file, but couldn't find sample code or help online, to be able to connect to Microstrategy and access data.

Any help towards this is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Did you look here ?

https://lw.microstrategy.com/msdz/MSDL/AnalyticsEnterprise/docs/DeveloperLibrary.htm#mergedProjects/genericcontent/topics/versiondiff/9.4.0_to_Analytics_Enterprise.htm

[image]

For me it was the first point when doing any MSTR SDK.

Data part:

[image]

Comment: I couldn't find any good material.
Could you please suggest some materials?